# Injecting a service into controller function in NestJS

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

In [nestjs](https://nestjs.com), is it possible to inject a service directly into controller function rather than constructor?

```
export class StuffController {
    // Injection via constructor like below works fine...
    // constructor(private readonly stuffService: StuffService) {
    // }

    @Get(':userId')
    index(@Req() req: Request, stuffService: StuffService) {
        // ... however, I'd like to inject it into this function.
    }
}
```

The reason is in my case some services are used only in scope of one function, not across all functions in a controller. Similar concept is available e.g. in [Asp .Net Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-controller-action-injection/).

I've tried playing with `@Inject()` and `@Injectable` decorators but with no success. Another idea would be to create a [custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) similar to how for example `@Req()` works, but is there a better way possibly provided out of the box?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Only 2 injections are possible at this date: constructor injection, and property-based injection. Not even [`ModuleRef`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) will help you with this.

Maybe your controller method **should** be in an other controller class, if it's doing something really specific? Just wondering.

Comment: @VinceOPS, thanks for responding. It's a good question whether it should be in another controller. In this case endpoints execute commands or queries, so I ended up with injecting a command (or query) bus into the constructor as nestjs docs describe [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs). This is probably the most readable and consistent way.